# How to run Rails console in test environment with Zeus?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, zeus

What I want to do is to run `rails console test` but with [Zeus](https://github.com/burke/zeus) gem, something like: `zeus console test`

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The solution is achieved by modifying your zeus.json file to include a new console command that will run in the test environment which I have called `test_console`.

Here is my entire **zeus.json** file, the only relevant bit being the part starting with `"test_console"`:

```
{
  "command": "ruby -rubygems -r./custom_plan -eZeus.go",

  "plan": {
    "boot": {
      "default_bundle": {
        "development_environment": {
          "prerake": {"rake": []},
          "runner": ["r"],
          "console": ["c"],
          "server": ["s"],
          "generate": ["g"],
          "destroy": ["d"],
          "dbconsole": []
        },
        "test_environment": {
          "cucumber_environment": {"cucumber": []},
          "test_helper": {"test": ["rspec", "testrb"]},
          "test_console": ["tc"]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

To enable test_console however, you will need to create a custom plan in your **custom_plan.rb** file as follows:

```
require 'zeus/rails'

class CustomPlan < Zeus::Rails
  def default_bundle_with_test_env
    ::Rails.env = 'test'
    ENV['RAILS_ENV'] = 'test'
    default_bundle
  end

  def test_console
    console
  end
end

Zeus.plan = CustomPlan.new
```

Note the default_bundle_with_test_env is needed, as is the test_console method which was defined above in your zeus.json file.

Finally, run: `zeus test_console` or `zeus tc`